# How can I make each promise take 2 seconds to complete in an async manner?

Tags: java, multithreading, promise, future, vert.x

Here is the code:

```
import io.vertx.core.Future; 
import io.vertx.core.Promise; 
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Task extends Thread { 
public static int sumEven(JsonArray numbers) {
List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
  int num = numbers.getInteger(i);
  Promise<Integer> promise = Promise.promise();
  try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Waiting");
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("InterruptedException");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  promise.complete(num);
  futures.add(promise.future());
}
futures = futures.stream().filter(f -> f.result() % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());

if (futures.isEmpty()) {
  return 0;
}

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
  sum += futures.get(i).result();
}
return sum;
}
}
```

Right now its just waited 2 seconds during each iteration so complete a promise. I want to make it so that each promise turns into a thread that will take 2 seconds to complete the promise.

My code is above so you can see what I have tried. Right now its just waiting 2 seconds in every iteration. I want it so that each thread takes 2 seconds in an async manner.

Comment: So I have a few questions for you to clarify for me, 1) why are you extending the Thread class? 2) why are you using a static method, 3) why are you using io.vertx package ?

Comment: Yes I realized I did not have to extend the thread class. The method is static because I was writing a JUnit 4 test for it. I am using Vertx because this assignment is what im doing to learn futures and promises in the vertex lib

Comment: I am not familiar with this library, but this code will run on the Main Thead and it is not creating any kind of parallel executions, I would suggest to read the docs for how to use this promise instancer you are creating, probably it should be passed to some kind of an executor, where the executor is responsible for executing some code and populating this promise instance with a fufure instance.